# Linear dependence between 2D vectors

Tags: vectors

A question on my book says the following:
Prove that any three vectors **u**,**v** and **w** are linearly dependent.

I don't see how this could work, if the vectors could be **any** three vectors, we can take into consideration the case where we assume that one or more is **0**.

If  one of the three vectors is **0**, then the statement could be rephrased as: prove that any two vectors are linearly dependent. This is an impossibility, so the original statement must also be impossible to prove.

Am I right in thinking this or am I missing something?

Comment: Please tell us exactly why you think it is 'legitimate', and why your statement can be rephrased as you did. (Lets say $u=v=w=0$. Then any two of these vectors are linearly dependent.) Please clarify your use of *any*, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/402073/109451

Comment: Linear dependence usually involves non zero vectors. Since the presence of the zero vector in a set makes that set always linearly dependent.

Comment: If fact if any of the vectors is $0$, then the set is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is of the form $\forall u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $u,v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent. That means that no matter what three vectors you choose, they must be linearly dependent. Of course $0$ might be one of the three vectors chosen, but the statement is much more general than that, since it is not essential that one of the three vectors be $0$.

To prove the statement, you could form the $3\times2$ matrix, call it $A$, with rows $u,v$ and $w$. The rank of $A$ shall be $\leq2$ which is $<3$, therefore $u,v,w$ are linearly dependent.